# How to play a mp4 video url in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to play a mp4 video from a url and i am using player class to play video inside my application instead of using browsersession, but i always get the error of unsupported file.

Please advise me how to use player to play a video url.

any reply is appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

... You can stream a mp4 video using the [Media Player](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/invocation/media_player.html) class. sample code on [BB support forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Open-video-url-in-default-media-player/td-p/2168917)...

Comment: My guess is that because the question mentioned the `BrowserSession` class, he/she is using the older BlackBerry Java OS, not BB 10.

Comment: I am developing blackberry app for BB os 7.1, So please suggest how to play mp4 video from url.